# How much ether was transferred in this transaction?

Tags: transactions, etherscan, hash

Is there any way to determine how much ether was transferred in the following transaction?

If so, how much was it?

##### Transaction of interest

```
{
      "hash": "0x83301a9389919316829e7d6cf4b083476f96f8a57e4373ba933c94ee8dc6def7",
      "nonce": "27",
      "transaction_index": "120",
      "from_address": "0xc4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b",
      "to_address": "0x03be5c903c727ee2c8c4e9bc0acc860cca4715e2",
      "value": "0",
      "gas": "41675",
      "gas_price": "24700000000",
      "input": "0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000f8571a95402cf5b25db184e5161118cd6c373eb80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a2a15d09519be00000",
      "receipt_cumulative_gas_used": "11967001",
      "receipt_gas_used": "29929",
      "receipt_contract_address": null,
      "receipt_root": null,
      "receipt_status": "1",
      "block_timestamp": "2022-04-10T19:36:11.000Z",
      "block_number": "14559834",
      "block_hash": "0x86ddd715f83c01ac25e82614ae44fdb27ed7f9770212a2cd2522e2671e61dc82",
      "transfer_index": [
        14559834,
        120
      ]
    },
```

For context, the above represents a single transaction which is the first in the series of transactions transcribed below.

##### All transactions

```
{
  "total": 32,
  "page": 0,
  "page_size": 500,
  "cursor": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhZGRyZXNzIjoiMHhjNGNkOTlhYmQ1YzY1ZDU0ZTEzNGMyNDEyZmEzMTU3YjQzMzZhODViIiwiY2hhaW4iOiJldGgiLCJ0b19ibG9jayI6IjEwODAxNzEyIiwiYmxvY2tfb2Zmc2V0IjoxLCJ0b3RhbCI6MzIsInBhZ2UiOjEsImxpbWl0Ijo1MDAsIm9mZnNldCI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNjUyMDI5NDAzfQ.t3YLF2T7YagiLd6SJc8SMKJCU4_Ap7t088ieSGSgMlw",
  "result": [
    {
      "hash": "0x83301a9389919316829e7d6cf4b083476f96f8a57e4373ba933c94ee8dc6def7",
      "nonce": "27",
      "transaction_index": "120",
      "from_address": "0xc4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b",
      "to_address": "0x03be5c903c727ee2c8c4e9bc0acc860cca4715e2",
      "value": "0",
      "gas": "41675",
      "gas_price": "24700000000",
      "input": "0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000f8571a95402cf5b25db184e5161118cd6c373eb80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a2a15d09519be00000",
      "receipt_cumulative_gas_used": "11967001",
      "receipt_gas_used": "29929",
      "receipt_contract_address": null,
      "receipt_root": null,
      "receipt_status": "1",
      "block_timestamp": "2022-04-10T19:36:11.000Z",
      "block_number": "14559834",
      "block_hash": "0x86ddd715f83c01ac25e82614ae44fdb27ed7f9770212a2cd2522e2671e61dc82",
      "transfer_index": [
        14559834,
        120
      ]
    },
    {
      "hash": "0xeeba63e2b9a3cabcbef1c02de2e0142e6eb00fdb78ecd824f66c9f6caae6c79a",
      "nonce": "26",
      "transaction_index": "21",
      "from_address": "0xc4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b",
      "to_address": "0x03be5c903c727ee2c8c4e9bc0acc860cca4715e2",
      "value": "0",
      "gas": "96204",
      "gas_price": "43761151821",
      "input": "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",
      "receipt_cumulative_gas_used": "1605219",
      "receipt_gas_used": "64136",
      "receipt_contract_address": null,
      "receipt_root": null,
      "receipt_status": "1",
      "block_timestamp": "2022-04-02T08:53:57.000Z",
      "block_number": "14505811",
      "block_hash": "0x0404e963af8a58171b4f0d6ddf85b385382075f8aa6705b9119f2e55ffced780",
      "transfer_index": [
        14505811,
        21
      ]
    },
    {
      "hash": "0x86eb0f592d510529ba1ab174c0b54ea527f371a931ae33d3890494ee95e6f56e",
      "nonce": "25",
      "transaction_index": "106",
      "from_address": "0xc4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b",
      "to_address": "0x03be5c903c727ee2c8c4e9bc0acc860cca4715e2",
      "value": "0",
      "gas": "121810",
      "gas_price": "88886563725",
      "input": "0xf9ed9f0300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c000000000000000000000000053912d7446ad89e050ed45338b5f09600284a8c3000000000000000000000000c4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005150ae84a8cdf000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d14afe000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000070300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000419792fa6d8113340df1a620dd7619a4583ddf75088e5b7e12229e9f35536edf0022e6c9cf28b3ac06dca7de77e1d0c37104b05a1bed2fd075d9b31298524819651b00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      "receipt_cumulative_gas_used": "6268971",
      "receipt_gas_used": "81207",
      "receipt_contract_address": null,
      "receipt_root": null,
      "receipt_status": "1",
      "block_timestamp": "2022-02-11T17:37:58.000Z",
      "block_number": "14186146",
      "block_hash": "0xd7f8c0a95f31a5de4a53f132bf6ba6f66e11447eed2b6411c36d162647b20105",
      "transfer_index": [
        14186146,
        106
      ]
    },
    {
      "hash": "0x23fe5398ffc2f02c8e3769851b8edd496016aa54703f84f4ae7bacf2c2026fe9",
      "nonce": "24",
      "transaction_index": "48",
      "from_address": "0xc4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b",
      "to_address": "0x03be5c903c727ee2c8c4e9bc0acc860cca4715e2",
      "value": "0",
      "gas": "62195",
      "gas_price": "149500000000",
      "input": "0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000661bd1df681a8293e856f766acaca1d7a660851800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006c6b935b8bbd400000",
      "receipt_cumulative_gas_used": "2414921",
      "receipt_gas_used": "47029",
      "receipt_contract_address": null,
      "receipt_root": null,
      "receipt_status": "1",
      "block_timestamp": "2021-10-29T09:15:57.000Z",
      "block_number": "13511235",
      "block_hash": "0xdcf23397f5184ec39edb67d5973cbcf78a1f80022026c1e91506749df93db0e4",
      "transfer_index": [
        13511235,
        48
      ]
    },
    {
      "hash": "0x649e9ac3d5928bb04e4fd6527eac902031b845557e4738a96e5ed4d400998422",
      "nonce": "23",
      "transaction_index": "263",
      "from_address": "0xc4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b",
      "to_address": "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7",
      "value": "0",
      "gas": "75851",
      "gas_price": "95500000000",
      "input": "0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000eddd5f3e2051ebbb3c4f1389d155969c5cd3c3ea00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000342770c0",
      "receipt_cumulative_gas_used": "22862241",
      "receipt_gas_used": "63209",
      "receipt_contract_address": null,
      "receipt_root": null,
      "receipt_status": "1",
      "block_timestamp": "2021-10-08T20:44:48.000Z",
      "block_number": "13380405",
      "block_hash": "0x52d6e6bd1080bd088770788da70b4ae6f14e3ce55f64a88016e9cfa3847520d5",
      "transfer_index": null
    },
    {
      "hash": "0x7c6d19f528136f4ad266dd43bc3a58ca931359b41eb09fa052750fcd2670790a",
      "nonce": "22",
      "transaction_index": "13",
      "from_address": "0xc4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b",
      "to_address": "0x03be5c903c727ee2c8c4e9bc0acc860cca4715e2",
      "value": "0",
      "gas": "121854",
      "gas_price": "37767144426",
      "input": "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",
      "receipt_cumulative_gas_used": "611111",
      "receipt_gas_used": "81236",
      "receipt_contract_address": null,
      "receipt_root": null,
      "receipt_status": "1",
      "block_timestamp": "2021-10-03T08:57:42.000Z",
      "block_number": "13345249",
      "block_hash": "0xeed8f8619cfeabdef97ccf4c6fa9bb8ba1206b6e8b457014b0ce372bf324c71f",
      "transfer_index": null
    },
    {
      "hash": "0xd57688527ba13fc35b70161cc42f7fbf53658c797411303f8b4a2ff709d6252b",
      "nonce": "21",
      "transaction_index": "109",
      "from_address": "0xc4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b",
      "to_address": "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7",
      "value": "0",
      "gas": "94813",
      "gas_price": "8000000000",
      "input": "0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000001ffdc9b9d1f830e431079daeabf2cfd0568610e40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000018ea7aa0",
      "receipt_cumulative_gas_used": "11498917",
      "receipt_gas_used": "63209",
      "receipt_contract_address": null,
      "receipt_root": null,
      "receipt_status": "1",
      "block_timestamp": "2021-06-19T07:38:56.000Z",
      "block_number": "12663529",
      "block_hash": "0x4663464066877dfc00da55a438ba2aee3da33c8fed3e2b8ffcb07b7933d11862",
      "transfer_index": null
    },
    {
      "hash": "0x0a1d9b6d8fdbbb8c3348ab7a0d09de6f1fefb6a510738decef823de1062893a4",
      "nonce": "20",
      "transaction_index": "194",
      "from_address": "0xc4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b",
      "to_address": "0xe592427a0aece92de3edee1f18e0157c05861564",
      "value": "0",
      "gas": "208888",
      "gas_price": "10000000000",
      "input": "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",
      "receipt_cumulative_gas_used": "11390740",
      "receipt_gas_used": "155837",
      "receipt_contract_address": null,
      "receipt_root": null,
      "receipt_status": "1",
      "block_timestamp": "2021-06-19T07:33:09.000Z",
      "block_number": "12663505",
      "block_hash": "0x371ac80f554b9f4d152b658ef22e3949508c4f8647573ec1754d0d85be09812e",
      "transfer_index": null
    },
    {
      "hash": "0x7599a7b2cacc04abca05ebc43dfb4d0438e9312698f6e9ccd09b442a2b021e6f",
      "nonce": "19",
      "transaction_index": "103",
      "from_address": "0xc4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b",
      "to_address": "0x4aa42145aa6ebf72e164c9bbc74fbd3788045016",
      "value": "0",
      "gas": "163420",
      "gas_price": "11000000000",
      "input": "0x3f7658fd000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000068c4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000015c4b818244ec5590999a7eb582519daacc28a9d975ad85ac638ba1c7b455f043b42c61bac93d812554aa42145aa6ebf72e164c9bbc74fbd378804501600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c4031b1c1c2785fba6197f836d6a842061ab063e01d2346743c700eeab5788976e074e9d3e04b7cb40d44f73b5160220bd6e79472b41ae551d42271aeeac0cf2fd336e2edce12c6fa64e8fc4d5c530b024c3e536968f94a395328427686474131cb4b7e305061c17c0735c7fc9614d8b4c7f33c47406d85614d0c81820d6aed0bcbb29aa385aeb4bba838537041efed10d01fd4c4f429712e9c9d0ea82aadf49fabe25f89273eb88656be84802206e489ed18ff788e9ef1ff27332d386562ac4cb14b2312c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      "receipt_cumulative_gas_used": "6303168",
      "receipt_gas_used": "161413",
      "receipt_contract_address": null,
      "receipt_root": null,
      "receipt_status": "1",
      "block_timestamp": "2021-06-19T07:31:12.000Z",
      "block_number": "12663496",
      "block_hash": "0x2a3c7078153cd22569ee52ad05a8b49bba78be4dd785841909ad84fb38703dc5",
      "transfer_index": null
    },
    {
      "hash": "0xf2a02355317289eea83d201b3fd017e0a5da25a3be6f3b09efb8cd884ccd7e8c",
      "nonce": "18",
      "transaction_index": "88",
      "from_address": "0xc4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b",
      "to_address": "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7",
      "value": "0",
      "gas": "75836",
      "gas_price": "135000000000",
      "input": "0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000005996001fd483f9da313581b0693011070eb18079000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ac0fda0",
      "receipt_cumulative_gas_used": "4373339",
      "receipt_gas_used": "63197",
      "receipt_contract_address": null,
      "receipt_root": null,
      "receipt_status": "1",
      "block_timestamp": "2021-04-16T05:46:26.000Z",
      "block_number": "12249295",
      "block_hash": "0x2de9c7f1a9094234a3e1d647d799499d5d15cedbeedbc5e39987d281bc6681c4",
      "transfer_index": null
    },
    {
      "hash": "0xe0e1c25d9fb066b98dd6c8b87dc401017e41420c470c0b97edc845fd864b7976",
      "nonce": "17",
      "transaction_index": "85",
      "from_address": "0xc4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b",
      "to_address": "0x88ad09518695c6c3712ac10a214be5109a655671",
      "value": "0",
      "gas": "210515",
      "gas_price": "90000000000",
      "input": "0xad58bdd1000000000000000000000000a0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48000000000000000000000000c4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000023cbe641",
      "receipt_cumulative_gas_used": "7960297",
      "receipt_gas_used": "158452",
      "receipt_contract_address": null,
      "receipt_root": null,
      "receipt_status": "1",
      "block_timestamp": "2021-03-29T07:44:53.000Z",
      "block_number": "12132865",
      "block_hash": "0x7c6a40e2e5c73b1591b2adeae83f9dc2b244537e7f35839e2708040bab6d9001",
      "transfer_index": null
    },
    {
      "hash": "0x7e43fde3bf626087f255cbb376de2a4752916f838551a5c03e879d1361aed41a",
      "nonce": "16",
      "transaction_index": "129",
      "from_address": "0xc4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b",
      "to_address": "0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48",
      "value": "0",
      "gas": "49829",
      "gas_price": "95000000000",
      "input": "0x095ea7b300000000000000000000000088ad09518695c6c3712ac10a214be5109a6556710000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000023cbe641",
      "receipt_cumulative_gas_used": "9363280",
      "receipt_gas_used": "49475",
      "receipt_contract_address": null,
      "receipt_root": null,
      "receipt_status": "1",
      "block_timestamp": "2021-03-29T07:43:27.000Z",
      "block_number": "12132855",
      "block_hash": "0x211baf223fd4cf6d8abd5b34976bcf8d72966e6189b8f2b3a4dd37a0dbde04ba",
      "transfer_index": null
    },
    {
      "hash": "0xd4312775db94ac556bd50585d8487ed5a42416856e7908e823ca9efdfd88eb93",
      "nonce": "15",
      "transaction_index": "130",
      "from_address": "0xc4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b",
      "to_address": "0x6a58eb0d64974e7e76e8f1080e53db86e348bceb",
      "value": "0",
      "gas": "48812",
      "gas_price": "224000000000",
      "input": "0x1aa3a008",
      "receipt_cumulative_gas_used": "7526292",
      "receipt_gas_used": "44375",
      "receipt_contract_address": null,
      "receipt_root": null,
      "receipt_status": "1",
      "block_timestamp": "2021-03-24T16:10:27.000Z",
      "block_number": "12102560",
      "block_hash": "0x58069c6610c7d0aa02ec433d96925e919969e0abc6dc51c7400070d304a89b9a",
      "transfer_index": null
    },
    {
      "hash": "0xed990ebdfbebbec6295fd5f4cf615171e50c86f2f635dfbbb76c00476c045528",
      "nonce": "14",
      "transaction_index": "119",
      "from_address": "0xc4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b",
      "to_address": "0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48",
      "value": "0",
      "gas": "55181",
      "gas_price": "133000000000",
      "input": "0x095ea7b30000000000000000000000007d2768de32b0b80b7a3454c06bdac94a69ddc7a9ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff",
      "receipt_cumulative_gas_used": "8613777",
      "receipt_gas_used": "49811",
      "receipt_contract_address": null,
      "receipt_root": null,
      "receipt_status": "1",
      "block_timestamp": "2021-02-25T08:39:59.000Z",
      "block_number": "11925302",
      "block_hash": "0x1a55fa27dafe20cfd1d1a3c9a003d3624e7680a2a0fd5f9dc44f48431e696c9d",
      "transfer_index": null
    },
    {
      "hash": "0x4a75720e6f72a93fd97d624aac4b5f123a13c351821fcdfe63a225ad6fbba400",
      "nonce": "4181553",
      "transaction_index": "0",
      "from_address": "0xd551234ae421e3bcba99a0da6d736074f22192ff",
      "to_address": "0xc4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b",
      "value": "68500000000000000",
      "gas": "21000",
      "gas_price": "246000000000",
      "input": "0x",
      "receipt_cumulative_gas_used": "21000",
      "receipt_gas_used": "21000",
      "receipt_contract_address": null,
      "receipt_root": null,
      "receipt_status": "1",
      "block_timestamp": "2021-02-24T09:41:53.000Z",
      "block_number": "11919064",
      "block_hash": "0x2f26d79033724fff970862ead83d7bd0d32bb8db183262b49dadc8e65d9daa8d",
      "transfer_index": null
    },
    {
      "hash": "0x5cda65c03813e38f438cdaec88e835ace0533d64fca7af25be379ce0902c6c35",
      "nonce": "13",
      "transaction_index": "190",
      "from_address": "0xc4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b",
      "to_address": "0xec2d495f20adf65cd26e9e250c8cd5d863609afd",
      "value": "0",
      "gas": "65754",
      "gas_price": "180000000000",
      "input": "0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000e412bee0f4830b9e703726e57059355a61bda0bf00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000029a2241af62c0000",
      "receipt_cumulative_gas_used": "10364121",
      "receipt_gas_used": "50754",
      "receipt_contract_address": null,
      "receipt_root": null,
      "receipt_status": "1",
      "block_timestamp": "2021-01-04T13:00:11.000Z",
      "block_number": "11588114",
      "block_hash": "0x84499bd946594173d491134e2215216ee9f8607e636015e1e168d1cdbb31cbd0",
      "transfer_index": null
    },
    {
      "hash": "0x178ffa86e98fa125c5b049adb4c404ff6c30634364ff68f34b0723fc1f95de69",
      "nonce": "12",
      "transaction_index": "178",
      "from_address": "0xc4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b",
      "to_address": "0xee9a08fc54bf53353398f946db4cb2447276f850",
      "value": "0",
      "gas": "65754",
      "gas_price": "186000000000",
      "input": "0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000324f064e0c1d3f84275fee08e6ef414235b97f540000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004563918244f40000",
      "receipt_cumulative_gas_used": "11971840",
      "receipt_gas_used": "50754",
      "receipt_contract_address": null,
      "receipt_root": null,
      "receipt_status": "1",
      "block_timestamp": "2021-01-04T12:45:51.000Z",
      "block_number": "11588055",
      "block_hash": "0x689f3c9150ccb66c61199da95d4ceb496012af7700201dc7e6b665e85198169a",
      "transfer_index": null
    },
    {
      "hash": "0xbd80386a11b40aaf1c764cae0c2b68fa00d3a1f2b2746eebadcd04c2927b5b82",
      "nonce": "3613937",
      "transaction_index": "44",
      "from_address": "0x0681d8db095565fe8a346fa0277bffde9c0edbbf",
      "to_address": "0xc4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b",
      "value": "37580000000000000",
      "gas": "21000",
      "gas_price": "636000000000",
      "input": "0x",
      "receipt_cumulative_gas_used": "1869422",
      "receipt_gas_used": "21000",
      "receipt_contract_address": null,
      "receipt_root": null,
      "receipt_status": "1",
      "block_timestamp": "2021-01-04T09:20:03.000Z",
      "block_number": "11587131",
      "block_hash": "0xe0398f8a77c6e0613a9768f3319f6a3ae3b2f54867e89244eeec083f53326faa",
      "transfer_index": null
    },
    {
      "hash": "0x8c4f61f4d5f0b0cd8b394e8f5f0238d564f067f6654415b2723d302b9eb35deb",
      "nonce": "11",
      "transaction_index": "80",
      "from_address": "0xc4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b",
      "to_address": "0x22cabb38295eaeccfede4e99af508052e3b74ca0",
      "value": "0",
      "gas": "49137",
      "gas_price": "57500000000",
      "input": "0x095ea7b3000000000000000000000000ea0f9e03138efcc7c98adbc4e698d0c158f99a0bffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff",
      "receipt_cumulative_gas_used": "8872657",
      "receipt_gas_used": "44670",
      "receipt_contract_address": null,
      "receipt_root": null,
      "receipt_status": "1",
      "block_timestamp": "2021-01-01T15:41:43.000Z",
      "block_number": "11569326",
      "block_hash": "0x83880e0bd9e5450536ae8630628e5817fda1c44e49ab51fbdd2abdbdcf723b0b",
      "transfer_index": null
    },
    {
      "hash": "0x844d44bbb0d55270c8f4914cbc10c55d7f3bfe40927a10a8fdb9d41665edec93",
      "nonce": "10",
      "transaction_index": "37",
      "from_address": "0xc4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b",
      "to_address": "0xa632fe8d996ca5bf80e20f8d4ef38a156c619df1",
      "value": "0",
      "gas": "169154",
      "gas_price": "57500000000",
      "input": "0xf552d91b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a76400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003716dfb0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005fef463c000000000000000000000000c4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b000000000000000000000000a0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48",
      "receipt_cumulative_gas_used": "3381473",
      "receipt_gas_used": "136765",
      "receipt_contract_address": null,
      "receipt_root": null,
      "receipt_status": "1",
      "block_timestamp": "2021-01-01T15:37:18.000Z",
      "block_number": "11569302",
      "block_hash": "0xf705dafab15dd8a483a72d46b66af5e6e45e168ea347df11bfcd59736e89f23f",
      "transfer_index": [
        11569302,
        37
      ]
    },
    {
      "hash": "0x1039af92e67dbf3e62af8399d42e4f17b40bae239c7fb29250003a53511fc5db",
      "nonce": "9",
      "transaction_index": "91",
      "from_address": "0xc4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b",
      "to_address": "0xbecaea7aa3629d4b7ddccf3a973bef09ff34d4b6",
      "value": "0",
      "gas": "49137",
      "gas_price": "50000000000",
      "input": "0x095ea7b3000000000000000000000000a632fe8d996ca5bf80e20f8d4ef38a156c619df1ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff",
      "receipt_cumulative_gas_used": "7814165",
      "receipt_gas_used": "44670",
      "receipt_contract_address": null,
      "receipt_root": null,
      "receipt_status": "1",
      "block_timestamp": "2021-01-01T15:36:44.000Z",
      "block_number": "11569298",
      "block_hash": "0x86b03f32d1a5039ad09cbe554178cdd97ff58abe7ae2619d4eb9dd62bb45c745",
      "transfer_index": null
    },
    {
      "hash": "0x7e710d3694c1b96ac5897f943de7d29320bb8cfe0d51fee5b611f83b33110ee0",
      "nonce": "8",
      "transaction_index": "188",
      "from_address": "0xc4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b",
      "to_address": "0x7671f9c37bfcee829f54d4bdd2a226930c91df7b",
      "value": "0",
      "gas": "169154",
      "gas_price": "63000000000",
      "input": "0xf552d91b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000707ca5d0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005fef452f000000000000000000000000c4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b000000000000000000000000a0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48",
      "receipt_cumulative_gas_used": "10127855",
      "receipt_gas_used": "136765",
      "receipt_contract_address": null,
      "receipt_root": null,
      "receipt_status": "1",
      "block_timestamp": "2021-01-01T15:32:55.000Z",
      "block_number": "11569279",
      "block_hash": "0x394e24372fa2e85ea3466ba29cf2bcc6c8781e7c8d713633844cd698d5de04a1",
      "transfer_index": null
    },
    {
      "hash": "0x044b576f623b8d324cbba1a7412e5b51570475edf8d6c2ddd37322272b80aa4b",
      "nonce": "7",
      "transaction_index": "208",
      "from_address": "0xc4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b",
      "to_address": "0x43688910273f199b8ae2ca018c13918fb3d37b58",
      "value": "0",
      "gas": "49137",
      "gas_price": "64000000000",
      "input": "0x095ea7b30000000000000000000000007671f9c37bfcee829f54d4bdd2a226930c91df7bffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff",
      "receipt_cumulative_gas_used": "11914902",
      "receipt_gas_used": "44670",
      "receipt_contract_address": null,
      "receipt_root": null,
      "receipt_status": "1",
      "block_timestamp": "2021-01-01T15:32:00.000Z",
      "block_number": "11569272",
      "block_hash": "0x74ec6cf1d2b57fce025d0640992a7975efca1f3387d169a3d17edd917ff0243f",
      "transfer_index": null
    },
    {
      "hash": "0x761b21a142a6442c9137390d48bdf96245a3d83e67b8333f4e5b29340f6f3523",
      "nonce": "6",
      "transaction_index": "138",
      "from_address": "0xc4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b",
      "to_address": "0xb40b148eb592ae5cc8a86eb7aad2b1af9e81bc02",
      "value": "500000000000000000",
      "gas": "21000",
      "gas_price": "44000000000",
      "input": "0x",
      "receipt_cumulative_gas_used": "8386711",
      "receipt_gas_used": "21000",
      "receipt_contract_address": null,
      "receipt_root": null,
      "receipt_status": "1",
      "block_timestamp": "2020-12-20T16:16:23.000Z",
      "block_number": "11491243",
      "block_hash": "0x87d31e393d08d7820e145caccfbb9a17f1b2d8e47cf4bbce5c23f10274c05dad",
      "transfer_index": [
        11491243,
        138
      ]
    },
    {
      "hash": "0x47dc35225039a72a144c05306753a9b65a72abfd5b1d36f0acb4cae1a30202c7",
      "nonce": "5",
      "transaction_index": "167",
      "from_address": "0xc4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b",
      "to_address": "0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d",
      "value": "0",
      "gas": "237240",
      "gas_price": "57000000000",
      "input": "0x18cbafe50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003d7b7070000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000189d3984e67872900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a0000000000000000000000000c4cd99abd5c65d54e134c2412fa3157b4336a85b000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005fcf9c830000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003000000000000000000000000a0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb480000000000000000000000006b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f000000000000000000000000c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2",
      "receipt_cumulative_gas_used": "8355856",
      "receipt_gas_used": "171261",
      "receipt_contract_address": null,
      "receipt_root": null,
      "receipt_status": "1",
      "block_timestamp": "2020-12-08T15:13:27.000Z",
      "block_number": "11412885",
      "block_hash": "0xa2fcb4e6c2c531d41bff617d9a9f3b197979bcb7fe7af6ba1fbc9627f807799d",
      "transfer_index": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see how much ETH was transferred, by taking the "value" variable and dividing it with 10"18.

The number you get is the amount of ETH sent. (Note the amount is only sent if the transaction passed).